# Why does this implementation of merge on a sorted linked list always set both lists to NULL when only one should?

Tags: c++, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Honestly, I've been at this for about 10 hours, trying method after method to get this to work. I'm trying to create a 3rd list that is 2 lists merged together and sorted from low to high(no duplicates), then set the first list's to the new list, thus merging the 2nd list into the 1st. But whenever I run the program, I get listData == NULL, even in test cases where newListCurr should absolutely be adding elements to newList. I've always had difficulty with linked lists so maybe I'm misunderstanding some fundamentals but I cannot for the life of me figure out this. The method needs to not declare a single new node, and can only have a time complexity of O(n), which is making this much harder. I've tried a couple approaches, like trying to slot them directly into listData (the first list), but there is a consistent issue with the curr pointers not actually affecting their respective listData.

EDIT: The lists are assumed to be ordered prior to merging.

Here is the merge method, everything else works as intended it's only the merge method that's messing up.

```
template <class ItemType>
void SortedList<ItemType>::merge(SortedList& list) {
    Node<ItemType> * curr1 = listData;
    Node<ItemType> * curr2 = list.listData;
    Node<ItemType> * newList = NULL;
    Node<ItemType> * newListCurr = newList;
    while(curr2 != NULL || curr1 != NULL) {
        if(curr2 == NULL) {
            newListCurr = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        }
        else if(curr1 == NULL) {
            newListCurr = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        }
        else if(curr1->info < curr2->info) {
            newListCurr = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        } else if (curr2->info < curr1->info) {
            newListCurr = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        }
        else if (curr1->info == curr2->info) {
            newListCurr = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        }
    }
    list.listData = NULL;
    listData = newList;
}
```

EDIT: I found a solution for those who may have this same issue. I needed to set newList and newListCurr to a node before I could modify the rest of newList using newListCurr. Here is my updated code:

```
template <class ItemType>
void SortedList<ItemType>::merge(SortedList& list) {
    Node<ItemType> * curr1 = listData;
    Node<ItemType> * curr2 = list.listData;
    Node<ItemType> * newList = NULL;
    Node<ItemType> * newListCurr = newList;
    if(curr2 != NULL || curr1!= NULL) {
        if(curr2 == NULL) {
            newListCurr = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
        } else if(curr1 == NULL) {
            newListCurr = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        } else if(curr1->info < curr2->info) {
            newListCurr = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
        } else if (curr2->info < curr1->info) {
            newListCurr = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        } else if (curr1->info == curr2->info) {
            newListCurr = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
        }
        newList = newListCurr;
    }
    while(curr2 != NULL || curr1 != NULL) {
        if(curr2 == NULL) {
            newListCurr->next = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        }
        else if(curr1 == NULL) {
            newListCurr->next = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        }
        else if(curr1->info < curr2->info) {

            newListCurr->next = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        } else if (curr2->info < curr1->info) {
            newListCurr->next = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        }
        else if (curr1->info == curr2->info) {
            newListCurr->next = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1->next;
            curr2 = curr2->next;
            newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
        }
    }
    list.listData = NULL;
    listData = newList;
}
```

Comment: I see `Node<ItemType> * newList = NULL;`, nothing that changes it, and then `listData = newList;`. Why do you expect `newList` to be anything but `NULL`?

Comment: Often people thinking about answering a question will take the code from the question, paste it into a text file, compile it, and run it to see what bugs are where for themselves. Often they will use debugging tools of varying sizes, shapes and purposes. It is in the asker's best interests to make this as easy as possible. Snippets of stand-alone code make this hard. There is no program to be run and in the process of making one the bug may be accidentally fixed or new bugs inserted. Line numbers in the code make this hard. They need to be removed before the code can be compiled.

Comment: to iterate over your list, U need a poinnter to pointer not only one pointer. Or make a recursive function and use a reference to pointer. Another thing, U didn't mentioned if your old two lists were ordered or not.

Comment: @Kevin yes but I set newListCurr to newList, then add nodes using newListCurr. newList just exists to be a reference to the head of the 3rd list. Unless I'm doing it wrong. How would you suggest adding to newList while maintaining a reference to its first node?

Comment: @anonymous ah, my bad, yes the lists are assumed to be ordered, I'll update the post.

Comment: @user4581301 the entirety of the code is pretty long I'm not really sure how to allow you to compile it without copy pasting everything.

Comment: @Nikhil Jindia If the lists are not sorted then I do not see where you are creating a new sorted list from one non-empty list.

Comment: Almost all problems can be distilled down into a `main` and a few support functions. Isolating the error before asking a question here is highly recommended as more often than not, isolating the bug allows you to identify and fix it without asking the question. Make a `main` that builds up two sorted lists, attempts to merge them, and produces the erroneous result. If doing this does not reveal the solution to you, ask questions about this simple program. Use [mcve] for inspiration.

Comment: @NikhilJindia Are the two lists preliminary sorted?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes the method that actually inserts the nodes into the list before merging sorts them.

Comment: @NikhilJindia If your `SortedList` has a function to add items to the end of the list (something like AddItem() or something like that), then you don't need all of this code to create the merged list, given that the two lists to merge are already sorted.  All you had to do is to have a pointer to each of the lists, and write a simple loop to call `NewList->AddItem(x)`, where `x` is the smaller of the two items in the lists.  Then increment the pointer of the list you chose the smaller value from.  This is no different in nature than doing a merge of two sorted arrays into a larger array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newList` is set to NULL at the top, and it's never reassigned.  When you set `self. listData = newList;` at the end, newList is still NULL.

Perhaps you think if you set `newListCurr` to something, it sets `newList` -- it does not. They are independent pointers.

Comment: Ok that appears to be my shortcoming. How can I keep a pointer to the first node in newList and add nodes to the end?

Comment: I'd check if newList is NULL in the loop and if it's not, set it to newListCurr at the end of the loop.  I am not running/testing this idea -- just a guess.  You need to set it once so you can build on it.

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks a ton, took your idea and kinda made it work with my code, but the concept of setting it once before I can build on it was what I was missing. I just run the logic once before to get the first node in place, then changed the loop to modify newListCurr->next instead of newListCurr itself. I'll update the post with the working code!

Answer (score 0):

In the original function code there are two problems. The first one is the pointer `newList` is not being changed within the function and always equal to NULL.

```
Node<ItemType> * newList = NULL;
```

This null-pointer is assigned to the data member `listData`

```
listData = newList;
```

The second problem is that you are always changing the pointer `newListCurr` instead of the current value of the pointer `newListCurr->next` as for example in this if statement

```
    if(curr2 == NULL) {
        newListCurr = curr1;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        curr1 = curr1->next;
        newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
    }
```

In the new updated function implementation you avoid this mistake because now you are indeed changing the data member `next` of the current pointer `newListCurr`

```
    if(curr2 == NULL) {
        newListCurr->next = curr1;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        curr1 = curr1->next;
        newListCurr = newListCurr->next;
```

Nevertheless the new implementation of the function is too complicated because the same code is in fact duplicated in the first if statement.

The function can be implemented simpler if to use pointers to pointers. I do not know how your class is defined so I defined my one simple class.

The function can insert duplicates but you can change it such a way using an additional if statement that duplicates were not inserted.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class ItemType>
class SortedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        ItemType info;
        Node *next;
    } *listData = nullptr;

public:
    void insert( const ItemType &info )
    {
        Node **tail = &listData;

        while ( *tail ) tail = &( *tail )->next;

        *tail = new Node { info, nullptr };
    }

    void merge( SortedList<ItemType> & list )
    {
        Node *newListData = nullptr;

        Node **current = &newListData;
        Node **first   = &listData;
        Node **second  = &list.listData;

        while ( *first && *second )
        {
            if ( ( *second )->info < ( *first )->info )
            {
                *current = *second;
                *second = ( *second )->next;
                current =  &( *current )->next;
            }
            else
            {
                *current = *first;
                *first = ( *first )->next;
                current =  &( *current )->next;
            }
        }

        while ( *first )
        {
            *current = *first;
            *first = ( *first )->next;
            current =  &( *current )->next;
        }

        while ( *second )
        {
            *current = *second;
            *second = ( *second )->next;
            current =  &( *current )->next;
        }

        listData = newListData;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const SortedList<ItemType> &list )
    {
        for ( const SortedList<ItemType>::Node *current = list.listData; current; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->info << " -> ";
        }

        return os << "null";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    SortedList<int> list1;
    SortedList<int> list2;

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) list1.insert( i );
        else list2.insert( i );
    }

    std::cout << list1 << '\n';
    std::cout << list2 << '\n';

    list1.merge( list2 );

    std::cout << list1 << '\n';
    std::cout << list2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 2 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> null
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> null
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
null
```